# War deployment on Tomcat in AZure Webapp

Tags: tomcat, azure-web-app-service

I have a Web app created in Azure App service which have tomcat enabled. Tomcat seems to be running fine. I am able to login to Manager and start war deployment. After the deployment reaches to 100% the page refresh or it actually starts the war deployment, the page displays "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.".

There seems to be some permission problem but not getting how specifically to resolve it.

Comment: See tomcat logs to resolve this issue, you will see there exactly what is the error / issue

Comment: Any progress now?

Answer (score 3):

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Per my experience, it is a **404 Not Found** error. It means the page which you requested is not found by your server. There are two reasons that can cause this problem.

1.Please make sure you were accessing the page using the right path.

2.The page is not published successfully from your development server.

I created a sample servlet web app on local and generate war package via command `mvn clean package`.

Please rename the war package to `ROOT.war` so that you do not need to add a suffix after access url.

[image]

Set tomcat version on portal.

[image]

Deploy the war package to azure kudu `/site/wwwroot/webapps` path via FTP.

[image]

[image]

Restart the web app and access your domain url `http://<your app name>.azurewebsites.net/`

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note:

I followed @Jay Gong's steps and it's very important that after you copy the `ROOT.war` file to **access your domain url `http://<your app name>.azurewebsites.net/`**, it seems that this step causes the tomcat to start.