# Deploying a .war on Azure WebApps TOMCAT server

Tags: azure, tomcat, azure-web-app-service

Hi all I need help with the deployment of a .war to a Azure Webapp with Tomcat 9.0 - linux OS.

The question is more less along the lines of [War deployment on Tomcat in AZure Webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430581/war-deployment-on-tomcat-in-azure-webapp).

I tried to follow the steps and experimented quite a bit.

I tried first to just ship a app.war to the /home/site/wwwroot/webapps directory. I thought that from there the magic would have happen with Azure Webapp unpacking the .war and correctly deploying the application.

I tried then to ship an unpacked app.war (tried as well with ROOT as per url with similar question above).

I used the following:

```
az webapp deploy --subscription <blabla> --resource-group <blabla> --name test32 --src-path ./spring-boot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war --target-path /home/site/wwwroot/webapps/app --clean true
```

Double checked with ssh. Everything was deployed correctly.

Can somebody tell me what AzureWebapp is doing and the correct way to deploy a .war on a TOMCAT server over there.

Still getting 404 error:

> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Official documentation could not help me enough.

Thanks

---

Edit: btw it is a Spring application the .war.

I see that a guy of the app service team suggests using Java SE for that. See  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/fe9e80d4-7263-46d4-891c-bf38ca4fcc25/azure-webapp-http-status-404-8211-not-found?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Would be still cool to understand how to make it work on TOMCAT as that is the server of choice in my org.

Comment: Could you please share us the document which you are following ?

Comment: Hi @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT - I am using the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/configure-language-java?pivots=platform-linux#gradle

Since the gradle deployment along that specifications failed I started to dig into the Kudu API specificiations which the az webapp deploy uses.

Comment: Hosting platform is windows or linux ?

Comment: Linux - it is mentioned at the beginning of the question.